# How to display the definition of a Stored Procedure in BigQuery?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a keyword or syntax in BigQuery to display the definition of a Stored Procedure after creating the procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  routine_catalog, 
  routine_schema, 
  routine_name, 
  routine_type, 
  routine_definition
FROM your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Obviously, you can add `WHERE routine_name = 'your_procedure_name'` to get only what you need instead of all

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is not a keyword for getting the stored procedure definition, but it can be retrieved from the BigQuery UI by clicking the Resources section -> Stored procedure ID   and you will find the field definition.

[image: [ATTACH an IMAGE]]

To complement the query in the other response, you can get the routine metadata by [querying the following](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-routines#syntax):

```
-- Returns metadata for routines in a single dataset.
SELECT routine_name, routine_definition FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE routine_name="{ROUTINE_NAME}";

-- Returns metadata for routines in a region.
SELECT routine_name, routine_definition FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE routine_name="{ROUTINE_NAME}";
```

This will return the  [Routine view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-routines#routines_view) including the ROUTINE_DEFINITION